# Atom won't keep my unsaved text content when it is reopen

Tags: atom

I just chose to use Atom as my Text editor. However, one thing I expect is when I open the app, I want my previous tabs being open even they are not saved ones. However, now what I got is everytime, I try to quit Atom, it asked me to save the file, if I chose "don't save", next time when I open it, the context will be gone. Any ideas how I can config it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Presumably it has a setting for this. Have you tried looking in the settings menu(s)? Have you tried Googling it? Keep in mind Atom is multi-platform, so you might well find your answer on a Windows or Mac or platform-agnostic site.

Comment: That will have to do with the workspace settings in atom..

Comment: Use this package to get that functionality: https://atom.io/packages/save-workspace

Answer (score 4):

This functionality is already included in Atom by default now.

- Settings -> Core Settings uncheck `Open Empty Editor on Start`
- Set `Restore Previous Windows on Start` to `Always`.
- Settings -> Packages -> autosave. In package settings check Enabled.

Also, restore will not work in Atom unless at least one Project has been added to the Project pane. You can add anything there. You can just add my Documents folder.